# ActivatedRoute can't retrieve data Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

When I call ActivatedRoute, I receive nothing in the objects

I try to get snapshot data form ActivatedRoute like this :

### Code in OutilsComponent :

```
constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,){}

ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this._activatedRoute.snapshot);
}
```

### Code in app-routing.module.ts :

```
{
    path: 'outils',
    component: OutilsComponent,
    data: {
      filDArianne: [{ url: 'outils', label: 'Outils', guarded: true }]
    }
},
```

### What console.log return :

This is when im on 'Outils' page

[image: image of console.log]

Why I have nothing in any ActivatedRoute item ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this. I'm able to print the data using both the ways. Please check.

https://plnkr.co/edit/4c49nIClYAzyCiKu

Comment: But in my case no data comes up, even if I write the way you do. I don't know what's going on :/ @NiravGhodadra (thx for your help)

Comment: your route data is under the data property, if you expand it in the console you will see ``filDArianne: [{ url: 'outils', label: 'Outils', guarded: true }]`

Comment: Try to use console.log(JSON.stringify(this._activatedRoute.snapshot)); to see all the json in console

Comment: Hey @PiwiTheKiwi, all my objects are empty ://